# Isotope images begin at center of element

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a site using Isotope from [isotope.metafizzy.co](http://isotope.metafizzy.co).

Text works fine, Centering and fully showing up.

BUG: On Tiles that I'm placing an image into, the images starts at 50%.  Even if the element is small, or width2, or clicked width.  it is always starting halfway to the right of the element.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Current Example: http://warpwars.net/Team/DanVioletSagmiller

Current Element Code (small part of the beginning):

```
<div id="container" class="clickable variable-sizes clearfix isotope">
    <div class="element justMe width2 height2 isotope-item " data-symbol="Dan Violet Sagmiller" data-category="halogen">
        Photo<br />
        <img src="/Content/dvs/DanVioletSagmiller.png" width="556" height="736" />
    </div>
    <div class="element majorProj " data-symbol="Teams RPG" data-category="post-transition">
        Teams RPG
    </div>
```

I have been using Chrome's inspector to look through the CSS affecting the image, and I can't find anything that would seem to suggest the image should be in the middle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an image directly to the root of the element does not work well.  However, wrapping the image in another div tag works perfectly.